# How to set a asp:label value using javascript and use it on server side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using javascript to count the no. of words and show it using a label lbl_words. then i have to calculate the cost per word. e.g. estimated_cost=word_count*cost
cost is fetched from the database and set to a label. Now i want to calculate estimated cost on button click.

Problem is that i cant't fetch lbl_words. Its value is set to null. Is there a way to fetch the client side values?
all controls used are asp controls.. Hope for a fast rply

I dont want to access values inside script.. I want to access them in .cs file on button click event. here is my code:

```
protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int cost, words;
    cost=Convert.ToInt16(lblcost.Text);
    words=Convert.ToInt16(lbl_words.Text);
    lbl_est_cost.Text = (cost*words).ToString();
}
```

lbl_words=word_count that is set using javascript
lblcost=cost fetched from the database

Comment: Can you show us how you're trying to access the control values? Keep in mind that ASP.NET controls' client-side IDs are not the same as the IDs you put in the tag markup. You have to do something like `document.getElementById('<%= myControl.ClientID %>').value;`

Comment: Label values are never passed back to the server. For your purpose, you need a control that renders to an HTML `input` tag when processed like `asp:TextBox`. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447160/asp-net-hidden-field-vs-invisible-textbox.

Comment: Can you please explain using an example.. @JamieSee